# Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, express, mern

I'm beginner in Reactjs and new here at StackOverflow. Actually, I'm trying to pass the data from backend to frontend. But instead of fetching the JSON data from the backend url, it is getting data from index.html of the frontend. My backend is nodejs. Basically, I want to get JSON data from backend and post the data in the console of frontend. But I'm getting this `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON` Can anyone help me to resolve this. [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs)[nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)

**Frontend code**

```
App.js
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {getOrder} from './ApiCalls.js'

function App() {

  const[values, setValues]=useState({
    amount:0,
    orderId:''
  })
  const{amount, orderId}=values

  useEffect(() => {
    createorder()
  }, [])
  
  
  const createorder=()=>{
    getOrder().then(response=>console.log(response))
  }

  const showRazorPay=()=>{
    const form=document.createElement('form')
    form.setAttribute('action',`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/payment/callback`);
    form.setAttribute('method',"POST");
    const script=document.createElement("script");
    script.src= "https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js";
    script.setAttribute("data-key",process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_KEY);
    script.setAttribute("data-amount", amount);
    script.setAttribute("data-prefill.contact","9561315545");
    script.setAttribute("data-order_id", orderId);
    script.setAttribute("data-prefill.name", "Priyanka Chaudhari");
    script.setAttribute("data-image", `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/logo`)
    script.setAttribute("data-buttontext","Donate Now!");
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.appendChild(script);
    const input= document.createElement("input");
    input.type="hidden";
    input.custom="Hidden Element";
  }
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
ApiCalls.js
export const getOrder=()=>{
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND}/createorder`,{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response=>response.json())
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}
```

**Backend Code**

```
App.js
const express=require('express')
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const cors=require('cors')
const app=express()
const PaymentRoute=require('./PaymentRoute')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.use('/api',PaymentRoute);


app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log(`App is running at 5000 port`)
})
```

```
PaymentRoute.js
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const{CreateOrder,paymentCallback,getLogo}=require('./PaymentController')

router.get('/createorder',CreateOrder);
router.post('/payment/callback',paymentCallback)
router.get('/logo',getLogo)
module.exports=router;
```

```
PaymentController.js
require('dotenv').config()
const Razorpay=require('razorpay')
const uniqueId=require('uniqid')
const path=require('path')


var instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: process.env.KEY_ID, key_secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY })

// instance.payments.fetch(paymentId)
exports.CreateOrder=(req,res)=>{
    var options = {
        amount: 50000,  // amount in the smallest currency unit
        currency: "INR",
        receipt: uniqueId()
      };
      instance.orders.create(options, function(err, order) {
        if(err){
        return    res.status(500).json({
                error:err
            })
        }
        res.json(order)
      });
}
exports.paymentCallback=(req,res)=>{

}
exports.getLogo=(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'donate-image.png'))
}
```

Comment: can you check in the network call what is the response you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `createorder` function name to `createOrder`, as in the `process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND/createorder`, `/createorder` is already present in my pathname so I think that was the reason for this error